# Changing Style Sheet javascript

Tags: javascript

I got this HTML code:

```html
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="javascript.js">
    <link id="pagestyle" href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="stylesheet1" > Default Style Sheet </button>
    <button id="stylesheet2" > Dark Style Sheet </button>
</body>
```

And in javascript.js I got this:

```js
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", sheet);  
}

function initate() {
    var style1 = document.getElementById("stylesheet1");
    var style2 = document.getElementById("stylesheet2");

    style1.onclick = swapStyleSheet("default".css);
    style2.onclick = swapStyleSheet("dark".css);
}

window.onload = initate;
```

I want to the style sheets to change while pressing this buttons. I can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Somewhat similar [post][1], may be helpful to answer your problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043147/multiple-style-sheets-only-disable-specific-group?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One guess would be the missing `.css` property, another would be the fact that `onclick` is not a function, but a result from invoking one:

Make all of `.css` a string and assign functions to `onclick`:

```
style1.onclick = function () { swapStyleSheet("default.css") };
style2.onclick = function () { swapStyleSheet("dark.css"); };
```

Answer (score 3):

Transform "default".css into "default.css".
Do the same for dark.css.

Then onclick takes a function as a value.

```
style1.onclick = function () { swapStyleSheet("default.css") };
style2.onclick = function () { swapStyleSheet("dark.css") };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('button').click(function() {
   let mainSheet = $('#pageStyle').attr('href');
   if(mainSheet == "default.css")
      $('#pageStyle').attr('href','dark.css');
   else
      $('#pageStyle').attr('href','default.css');
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello it Won't work until you add onclick="" property in html
So the final version will look like this:
**html**

```
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="javascript.js">
    <link id="pagestyle" href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="stylesheet1" onclick="initate();"> Default Style Sheet </button>
    <button id="stylesheet2" onclick="onclick="initate();"> Dark Style Sheet </button>
</body>
```

**Javascript file**

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", sheet);  
}

function initate() {
    var style1 = document.getElementById("stylesheet1");
    var style2 = document.getElementById("stylesheet2");

    style1.onclick = swapStyleSheet("default.css");
    style2.onclick = swapStyleSheet("dark.css");
}
```

Comment: Can you check your answer? I think you put an extra onclick in there.