# Changing a PHP variable when selecting an option from a select box

Tags: html, css

Basicly what I want to do is to change the stylesheet when the user selects the one they whant from a select box. To do that there would be a variable called $_SESSION['style']. What's the best way to change the variable when clicking it from the select box? (without clicking a submit button). Is it possible to change the stylesheet without reloading the whole page?

Thanksss! :)

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, so if you want it to actually change when you use the select box (immediately), use Javascript.  Here's a SO solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292997/changing-style-sheet-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can dynamically inject a CSS file when the select box is updated.

```
<select onchange="changecss(this.value);">
...
</select>

<script>
function changecss(value){
  //based on the value, pick a style sheet here
  var cssname='pick your own css file';

  csl=document.createElement('link');
  csl.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
  csl.setAttribute('type','text/css');
  csl.setAttribute('href',cssname);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(csl);

}
</script>
```

Edit:

I have seen code that directly change the src value of the current css inclusion. This doesn't not work in some versions of IE, because the browser is not "notified" of a DOM change, and your page is therefore unaffected. Inserting new CSS node in the DOM works more reliably.

With this [Ajax wrapper](http://www.antradar.com/docs-nano-ajax-manual) you can dynamically load the CSS file in one line:

```
<script src="http://www.antradar.com/nano.js"></script>
<script>
ajxcss(self.cssloader,'newcss.css');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is a server-side language that cannot update the data in the user's browser (no "push"), you need a client-side script for the change of the stylesheet without having to reload the page. Changing the stylesheet is possible with javascript. Because your stylesheet filename is stored in a (server-side) session variable, you've got 2 options:

- Render the filename into the site (e.g. by echoing it into the javascript code as a variable), so that it can be used by the client side script.
- Use an ajax call from the client side script, to get the filename from a PHP script ("pull"), that ouputs the session variable.

However, this might be too much overhead*. Maybe you should consider hardcoding the stylesheet filename into the javascript.

*) if you are using a javascript framework like jQuery or MooTools such things can be implemented easily...

---

Edit: I just recognized, that you've got a selectbox of items. In this case you surely want to go with the first option: Create the selectbox via PHP and for example use the filenames of the stylesheets as the values. You can than use javascript to change the stylesheet when a `onSelectedIndexChanged` happens.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't say anything about using javaScript in my question, but that was actually the idea. I'm just so new at javaScript and therefore I'm quite lost. I've been reading lots of questions from other people about that and I just don't know where to start (nothing seems to work for me!)

Comment: @Laia Are you using a javascript framework? This can help you to get an easier start, since you don't have to struggle with the way different browsers interpret your code.