# "Full site" option on mobile responsive website

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm working on a website that is responsive for mobile. We want to be able to have a "full site" button when it's viewed on a mobile device so users can see the normal website without responsive styling.

I'm thinking on click of the "full site" button I can remove the media queries stylesheet. But that doesn't overwrite the viewport setting that I have:

And even if I could change the site at the click of a button, what happens when the user navigates to a new page?

Any ideas for the best way to handle this? Is it even possible? Thanks!

http://sunniebrook.com

Comment: You could just change the style sheet for a non-responsive version. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14292997/1864610

Comment: Why not make the "full site" be responsive?

Comment: @MikeW I agree with you. But you could also update the meta-viewport tag so it is not "device-width" anymore. I think it's better than creating 2 different stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

There's this small blog post on css-tricks.com which I find pretty cool:
http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/

Which led me to this other blog post:
http://creativeandcode.com/responsive-view-full-site/

(Just put your wanted width in the meta viewport tag ;-) ).

Comment: You would set a cookie based on their clicking of the button. None of the options on css-tricks is good for all mobile devices, or it wasn't at the time.