# Use list instead of option for dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to be able to change the style of a page based on a dropdown list. I have a dropdown form as an option list, and using JS that are currently selecting from CSS on the page. This needs to apply a separate stylesheet (style1.css, style2.css, etc) on click/change of the dropdown based on the dropdown list item, instead of the option select.

**HTML**

**Option select**

```
<div class="et-select-wrapper">
  <div class="et-select-wrapper" style="margin:0">
     <select id="styleSwitcher">
            <option value="default">Default</option>
            <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**List Items - 
NEEDS TO WORK WITH LIST ITEM (BELOW) INSTEAD OF THE ABOVE OPTION**

**LIST ITEMS**

```
<button class="et-icon-down-arrow" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"> 
</span> Page Style</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="styleSwitcher">
  <li><a href="#" value="default">Default</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value="wcag">WCAG</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    window.onload = function() {
  function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
      obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;
      obj[type + fn] = function() {
        obj['e' + type + fn](window.event);
      }
      obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);
    } else obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
  }

  function switchStyles() {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex],
      className = selectedOption.value;
    document.body.className = className;
  }
  var styleSwitcher = document.getElementById("styleSwitcher");
  addEvent(styleSwitcher, "change", switchStyles);
}
```

===========================================================================

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution for what I needed here: http://test.unintentionallyblank.co.uk/switcher.html

By applying the function `setStyleSheet` to the `li` item in the dropdown like so:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown"><button class="et-icon-eye"> Style Selector</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:setStyleSheet('arial')">Arial</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setStyleSheet('open-sans')">Open Sans</a></li>
</ul>
```

and using the javascript from here: 
http://test.unintentionallyblank.co.uk/switcherpart1.js

which selects from a list of external stylesheets on the page, I'm able to change the pages style on select from the `li` list.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're using `li` tags instead of a `select`?

Comment: insert form elements in your list such as label + radio input (hidden or not via css) , and it will work. list on its own is not a form ;)

Comment: @rac, how can I rewrite the JS to work with select options instead of li list?

Comment: Matt, I think I might have answered your question.

Comment: @dkellner, I'm a bit unsure of the implementation of your answer. I found another way of doing this with jquery, but it still isn't functioning correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/phgv8tzy/

Comment: @Matt - I've updated my answer. It shouldn't be very hard from this point. If I understand what you're trying to do here, all you need to change is styleSwitcher, all other parts (of my example) can remain more or less the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style switcher (UL) doesn't have a "change" event, it doesn't *change* when you click things - it's a LIST, not a form control.  It's a static element on your page, like a text or something.  Bind your switchStyle() on "click" event of LI-s, instead.

Also, consider jQuery.  It saves you a lot of work around the events:

```
$("li").on("click",switchStyles);
```

**UPDATE**

I've created a minimal demo of how you can react on LI clicks:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="1"> Style 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="2"> Style 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="3"> Style 3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="4"> Style 4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="5"> Style 5 </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="colorMe">
        <br><br><br>
    </div>

    <script>

        function styleSwitcher(x) {
            var colors = ["blue","green","red","purple","orange"];
            $(".colorMe").css("background-color",colors[--x]);
        }


        $("li > a").on("click",function() {

            var n = $(this).data("value");
            styleSwitcher(n);

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

(Also a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkellner/j45abdc0/) for this)
Now you can apply your own method of switching styles.

**UPDATE II**

Here's another version with changing stylesheets:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<link id="customStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="theme.peace.css">
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="ocean"> Ocean Blue Theme </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="darko"> Dark Theme </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="flame"> Flaming Red Theme </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="peace"> Peaceful Nature Theme </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="steam"> Steampunk Theme </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="colorMe">
        <br><br><br>
    </div>

    <script>

        function styleSwitcher(t) {
            var cssName = "theme."+t+".css";
            document.getElementById("customStyle").setAttribute("href",cssName);  
        }


        $("li > a").on("click",function() {

            var theme = $(this).data("value");
            styleSwitcher(theme);

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have to properly named css files (like *theme.ocean.css*) in the proper directory - or update the name composition part if you have them somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for steering in the right direction. I need to be able to apply this to a dropdown list and choose from an array of style sheets, which are then applied to the head of the page. Here's an edited version of your sample in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phgv8tzy/2/. Ideas?

Comment: Your approach is almost fine - check out this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292997/changing-style-sheet-javascript

Comment: @Matt - also there's another update with another example.  Give it a try; I can't add a fiddle this time.

Comment: Combining the code from that stackoverflow link and my own, its much closer. It's not functioning though and changing out the stylesheet.
https://jsfiddle.net/33pLezny/2/

Comment: It's because you're assigning a function RESULT to your click events.  This: "style1.onclick = swapStyleSheet(...)" - means that you're calling swapStyleSheet and the returned value will go into onclick.  Now with your code this thing is not trivial to fix - how'bout trying what I suggested?

Comment: I found a solution externally, but due to your help, I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thanks!