# Javascript/HTML5: Fullscreen Video Source (Webcam or similar)

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, fullscreen

I was able to follow the tutorial for the Fullscreen API here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

HTML:

```
  <video autoplay
      id = "video"
      src="SampleVideo.mp4">
      <script src="fullscreen.js"></script>
  </video>
```

JS:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {

    var elem = document.getElementById("video");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }

  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('enter')
    toggleFullScreen();
  }
}, false);
```

And then I followed the tutorial here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

JS:

```
const hdConstraints = {
  video: {width: {min: 1280}, height: {min: 720}}
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(hdConstraints).
  then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});

const video = document.querySelector('video');

const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const audioSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
const videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(gotDevices).then(getStream).catch(handleError);

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label ||
        'microphone ' + (audioSelect.length + 1);
      audioSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'camera ' +
        (videoSelect.length + 1);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else {
      console.log('Found another kind of device: ', deviceInfo);
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (window.stream) {
    window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      track.stop();
    });
  }

  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      deviceId: {exact: audioSelect.value}
    },
    video: {
      deviceId: {exact: videoSelect.value}
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error('Error: ', error);
}
```

And I am wondering why I couldn't just remove the `src` in the HTML and consolidate the 2 js files together and have a fullscreen webcam. Is there a limitation for the use of the fullscreen API to videos only i.e. not a video source?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: No there is no such limitation. Can you show how you "merged" this scripts together? https://jsfiddle.net/kv6x2tf7/

Comment: Well I can see yours works! I will take a look at the difference now

Comment: Well regardless of the diffference, your solution works in my environment so if you post as an answer I will accept it @Kaiido

Comment: Since I don’t know what happens to the video div element using the Fullscreen API method, I actually ended up using a change style sheet function to enlarge and center the video in document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Kaiido's answer: https://jsfiddle.net/kv6x2tf7/

HTML:

```
<select id="audioSource">
</select>
<select id="videoSource">
</select>
<video id="video" muted autoplay></video>
```

JS:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {

    var elem = document.getElementById("video");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }

  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('enter')
    toggleFullScreen();
  }
}, false);

const hdConstraints = {
  video: {width: {min: 1280}, height: {min: 720}}
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(hdConstraints).
  then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});

const video = document.querySelector('video');

const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const audioSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
const videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(gotDevices).then(getStream).catch(handleError);

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label ||
        'microphone ' + (audioSelect.length + 1);
      audioSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'camera ' +
        (videoSelect.length + 1);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else {
      console.log('Found another kind of device: ', deviceInfo);
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (window.stream) {
    window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      track.stop();
    });
  }

  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      deviceId: {exact: audioSelect.value}
    },
    video: {
      deviceId: {exact: videoSelect.value}
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error('Error: ', error);
}
```

or see style sheet changing as mentioned here:

[Changing Style Sheet javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292997/changing-style-sheet-javascript)