# How to fully replace the CSS styling of a page or its header with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 different CSS files describing different color schemes and layout positions. I want to change between the 2 so I need to load them dynamically.

I tried doing the following to clear the CSS styling:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

However it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Style Sheet javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292997/changing-style-sheet-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

To change between them, you'd do it like this:

```
function cssFileOne() {
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
    link.setAttribute("href", "fileOne.css");
}

function cssFileTwo() {
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
    link.setAttribute("href", "fileTwo.css");
}
```

Then call those functions whenever you want to change the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you can also set id on link and change href dynamically

like

```
  <link id="mycss" rel="stylesheet"
```

and then use

```
document.getElementById("mycss").href = "your css link"
```