# How to change BACK with onchange with a switch in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a website, and want to create a dark/light mode. I have a switch that switches when clicked, and it successfully changes to my second css stylesheet. How should I go about switching BACK to the original stylesheet?

HTML-

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
<script>
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'assets/css/main2.css');
  }
</script>
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="swapStyleSheet()"">
    <span class=" slider"></span>
</label>
```

[Using this switch style](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Style Sheet javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292997/changing-style-sheet-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code I hope it's helpful for you.

```
 <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script>
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    if($(sheet).prop("checked") == true){
       document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'main2.css');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'main.css');
    }

  }
</script>

<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="swapStyleSheet(this)">
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen the checkbox. If it is checked or not. You can give this code a try. This should work.

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
<script>
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked){
     document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'assets/css/main2.css');
    }else{
      document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'assets/css/default.css');
    }
  }
</script>
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onchange="swapStyleSheet()"">
    <span class=" slider"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.href` property it's a lot shorter than `.setAttribute()`. A functioning demo can be reviewed [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/xF6I0Z7oyiYj9ZsMvYHx/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <input id='switch' type="checkbox">

  <script>
     document.querySelector('#switch').onchange = swap;

function swap(e) {
  document.querySelector('link').href = this.checked ? 'alt.css' : 'default.css';
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
<script>
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    switch(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked) {
    case true:
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'assets/css/main2.css');
    break;
    default:
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 'assets/css/default.css');
}
</script>
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onchange="swapStyleSheet()"">
    <span class=" slider"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: your code will throw error. You will get syntexerror.