# Switch between 2 stylesheets and perpetuate user preference with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have two images (a moon and a sun) and two different style sheets for the dark and light page themes. The dark mode is the default. To change to the light mode, you click on the image of the sun.

I am able to switch between the stylesheets. However, **I don't know how to store the chosen theme.** I want users to be able to have their style preference persist, even after refreshing the page or changing the page (on the same website).

I have put some examples of my code below. I hope someone can help me to make sense of local storage.

**Relevant html**

```
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles-dark.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link class="favicon" rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />  
  </head>
 
  <body>
 
    <header id="flex-box-header">
      <h1 id="nameHeading">MY NAME</h1>
      <!-- 'Dark Mode' will be the default --> 
      <div class="toggle">
        <div class="tooltip">
          <img class="displayButton" id="dark" src="moon - light.png" alt="dark mode" width="90.82px" height="76px">
          <span class="tooltiptext" id="textDark">Dark Mode</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip">
          <img class="displayButton" id="light" src="sun.jpg" alt="light mode" width="83.56px" height="62.02px">
          <span class="tooltiptext" id="textLight">Light Mode</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

**This JavaScript works to switch between themes, but how do I save the user preference, using local storage?**

```
// Button selection
const buttonLight = document.getElementById("light");
const buttonDark = document.getElementById("dark");

// Style selection
const lightStyle = "styles-light.css";
const darkStyle = "styles-dark.css";

// Select the stylesheet <link>
const theme = document.querySelector(".theme-link");

// Listen for a click on the sun button (buttonLight)
buttonLight.addEventListener("click", function() {
    theme.href = lightStyle;
    // different sun for light theme
    document.getElementById("light").src = "sun - light.png";
    document.querySelector(".favicon").href = "favicon-light.ico";
  });

// Listen for a click on the moon button (buttonDark)
buttonDark.addEventListener("click", function() {
    theme.href = darkStyle;
    // different sun for dark theme
    document.getElementById("light").src="sun.jpg";
    document.querySelector(".favicon").href = "favicon.ico";
  });
```

**JavaScript - trying to use local storage and failing**

```
function toggle(theme) {
    var styleSheet = document.getElementById("theme");
    if (theme != styleSheet.href) styleSheet.href = theme;
    document.getElementById("light").src.onClick = styleSheet.href === "styles-light.css";
  }
  window.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || document.getElementById("theme").href;
    toggle(theme);
    document.getElementById("light").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var theme = this.onClick ? "styles-light.css" : "styles-dark.css"
      toggle(theme);  
      localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    })
  })
```

Comment: use CSS vars for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Style Sheet javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292997/changing-style-sheet-javascript)

Comment: Hi there. I already know how to change the stylesheets with a button but I don't know how to store the user preferences. Thank you for the advice though

Comment: What is it about the local storage solution that  isn't working?  Does it just not recall the theme?  Does it take a moment to redo the theme?  Does the theme only re-apply on a click?  What is your exact expectation and what is happening now?  How have you tried to debug that?

Comment: Hi @zero298 I just don't know how to implement it correctly. With the example above, "trying to use local storage and failing", it doesn't even switch between themes at all. When you click on the sun image, it flashes once and then stays on the dark theme, instead of switching to the light theme.

I have been doing a lot of reading and can't figure out how to implement local storage with two CSS files. It seems as though most of the examples use classes.

Comment: @zero how would you suggest debugging?

Comment: My guess is that your window and light event listener are competing.  Why do you have a window click event listener?  Why not _just_ the light listener?  That window click listener is probably running **in addition to** the light click listener every time you click the light.  You're probably also adding multiple listeners every time you click the window.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!
It has FOIT (Flash Of Incorrect Theme) but I'm just so relieved the user preferences are saving. I will work on eliminating the FOIT on another day.

JavaScript

```
// Button selection
const buttonLight = document.getElementById("light");
const buttonDark = document.getElementById("dark");

// Style selection
const lightStyle = "styles-light.css";
const darkStyle = "styles-dark.css";

// Select the stylesheet <link>
const theme = document.getElementById("theme");

function lightFunction() {
  theme.href = lightStyle;
  // different sun for dark theme
  document.getElementById("light").src="sun - light.png";
  document.querySelector(".favicon").href = "favicon-light.ico";
  window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
}

function darkFunction() {
  theme.href = darkStyle;
  // different sun for dark theme
  document.getElementById("light").src="sun.jpg";
  document.querySelector(".favicon").href = "favicon.ico";
  window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
}

// Listen for a click on the sun button (buttonLight)
buttonLight.addEventListener("click", lightFunction);

// Listen for a click on the moon button (buttonDark)
buttonDark.addEventListener("click", darkFunction);

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  darkFunction();
} else {
  lightFunction();
}
```